# jquery loop 3items and repeat it by decrement it

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to create a jquery function to increment or decrement value every 3seconds using windows.interval.

here is the current target :

1st : 1,2,3
after 3 seconds
2nd : 3,1,2
after 3 seconds
3rd : 2,3,1
after 3 seconds
4th : 1,2,3

is there anyway to achieve that in jquery?

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    /// call your function here

    $('.item-3').css({
        'top': '-100px'
    });
    $('.item-1').animate({
        top: "100px",
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('.item-2').animate({
        top: "200px",
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $('.item-3').animate({
        top: "0px",
    }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

}, 5000);
```

I can not use the append or prepend as the item inside contains an flash object that I can not afford to loose the state, as if I use  append or prepend, I will have to reclick the flash object inside the div.item-x and that is not what I am wanting.

thank you

Comment: Can you provide some more granular details that what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Is it related to increment/decrement or you want to setup some thing like slider? Based on your code, it looks that you want to setup something related to slider. Like this: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/

Is this the same thing that you want to setup?

Comment: I wanted to setup a semi animation but can not use the sorgalla jcarousel because the inside the element I insert a flash object where when if I used sorgalla it will not run the flash once its looped back into the 1st object, so I just need my current functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, here I have mentioned some code. Please try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
                <ul>
                    <li><img src="photo1.jpg" alt="photo1" /></li>
                    <li><img src="photo2.jpg" alt="photo2" /></li>
                    <li><img src="photo3.jpg" alt="photo3" /></li>
                    <li><img src="photo4.jpg" alt="photo4" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow{
                    margin:0 auto;
                    height:155px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 465px;
                }

                #slideshow ul{
                    list-style: none;
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    position: absolute;
                }

                #slideshow li{
                    float:left;
                    padding:2.5px;
                }
```

**JS**

```
//an image width in pixels 
            var imageWidth = 155;

            //DOM and all content is loaded 
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var currentImage = 0;

            //set image count 
            var allImages = $('#slideshow li').length;

            //setup slideshow frame width
            $('#slideshow ul').width(allImages*imageWidth);

            setInterval(executeSlideShow,3000);

            function executeSlideShow()
            {
                //increase image counter
                currentImage++;
                //if we are at the end let set it to 0
                if(currentImage>=allImages) currentImage = 0;
                //calcualte and set position
                setFramePosition(currentImage);
            }

        });


        //calculate the slideshow frame position and animate it to the new position
        function setFramePosition(pos){

            //calculate position
            var px = imageWidth*pos*-1;
            //set ul left position
            $('#slideshow ul').animate({
                left: px
            }, 300);
        }
```

This code will not fulfill your exact requirement but yes, it will help you to achieve that and it will also work with your flash objects. In HTML you can replace your flash objects with Images.

Hope this will help you.